# How to prevent editing another row, if current row is dirty?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have 3 rows, while Im editing the seond one, there is a change that havent been saved.

[image]

How can I prevent the first and third row from being (clicked) edited, while the second one is dirty?

In other words, I want to force the user to click cancel if they want to change row 1 or row 3.

I tried using the edit function, but it triger way later after the second row is closed, so I cant detect that second row was being edited.

```
$("#table").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: mysource,
            pageable: true,
            editable: "inline",
            serverFiltering: true,
            edit: function (e) {
               // ?????
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cancel event https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/cancel

But the normal behaviour of the inline edit is when you click on a new edit inline button the previous edit is cancelled. Please see the example: 
https://demos.telerik.com/php-ui/grid/editing-inline